# Why context.SaveChange doesn't throw Exception for a unique index or an non existant foreign key

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, code-first, ef-core-3.1

I'm developing some API with EF Core 3.1 and an in-memory database.

I have some issues with the following code. I can't generate exception for the duplicate Name and for an non-existing foreign key in the same table.

```
public class Category
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Category> Children { get; set; }
}

public class ItemDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ItemDbContext(DbContextOptions<ItemDbContext> options)
        : base(options) {}
        
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("s_items");

        GetCategoryBuilder(modelBuilder);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    
    private void GetCategoryBuilder(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>(
            entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(c => c.Id)
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnName("CATE_ID")
                        .HasMaxLength(40);

                entity.Property(c => c.Name)
                        .IsRequired()
                        .IsFixedLength(false)
                        .IsUnicode()
                        .HasColumnName("CATE_NAME")
                        .HasMaxLength(50);

                entity.Property(c => c.CreationDate)
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnName("CATE_CREATION_DATE")
                        .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                entity.Property(c => c.LastModifiedDate)
                        .IsRequired(false)
                        .HasColumnName("CATE_UPDATE_DATE")
                        .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnUpdate();

                entity.Property(c => c.IsActive)
                        .HasColumnName("CATE_ACTIVE")
                        .HasDefaultValue(true)
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();

                entity.Property(c => c.ParentId)
                        .IsFixedLength(true)
                        .HasColumnName("CATE_PARENT_ID")
                        .HasMaxLength(40);
            }
        );

        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
            .HasOne(c => c.Parent)
            .WithMany(c => c.Children)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_CATE_PARENT");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
            .ToTable("Categories")
            .HasKey(c => c.Id)
            .HasName("PK_CATE");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
            .HasIndex(u => u.Name)
            .IsUnique(true)
            .HasName("UK_CATE_NAME");
    }
}

public class CategoryRepository : ICategoryRepository
{
    private readonly ItemDbContext _context;
    
    public CreateCategoryRepository(ItemDbContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        _context = context;
    }
    
    public Category Create(Category item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));
        }

        Category result = null;

        try
        {
            _context.Categories.Add(item);
            int nbRowsImpacted = _context.SaveChanges();

            if (nbRowsImpacted == 1)
            {
                result = item;
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            var message = "The instance of entity type 'Category' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.";

            if (ex.Message == message)
            {
                throw new DBConcurrencyException("There is already exists a similar category");
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            var message = "An item with the same key has already been added.";

            if (ex.Message.StartsWith(message))
            {
                throw new DBConcurrencyException("There is already exists a similar category");
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class CategoryRepository
{
    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("Category_Repository")]
    public void Category_Create_NotExistantParentId()
    {
        #region Arrange
        IServiceProvider provider = GetServiceProvider(
            DatabaseType.InMemory,
            injectCreateCategoryRepository: true);
        ItemDbContext context = provider.GetRequiredService<ItemDbContext>();
        IList<Product> products = SeedInMemory.GetProducts();
        context.Products.AddRange(products);
        context.SaveChanges();

        Category category = new Category()
        {
            Id = CategoryId.New(),
            Name = "Name",
            CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
            IsActive = true,
            ParentId = CategoryId.New()
        };

        ICategoryRepository repository = provider.GetRequiredService<ICategoryRepository>();
        var message = "There is already exists a similar category";
        #endregion

        #region Assert
        var result = Assert.ThrowsException<DBConcurrencyException>(() => repository.Create(category));
        Assert.AreEqual(message, result.Message);
        #endregion
    }
    
    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("CreateCategory_Repository")]
    public void CreateCategory_Create_DuplicateName()
    {
        #region Arrange
        IServiceProvider provider = GetServiceProvider(
            DatabaseType.InMemory,
            injectCreateCategoryRepository: true);
        ItemDbContext context = provider.GetRequiredService<ItemDbContext>();
        IList<Product> products = SeedInMemory.GetProducts();
        context.Products.AddRange(products);
        context.SaveChanges();

        Category category = new Category()
        {
            Id = CategoryId.New(),
            Name = context.Categories.FirstOrDefault().Name,
            CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
            IsActive = true
        };
        ICategoryRepository repository = provider.GetRequiredService<ICategoryRepository>();
        var message = "There is already exists a similar category";
        #endregion

        #region Assert
        var result = Assert.ThrowsException<DBConcurrencyException>(() => repository.Create(category));
        Assert.AreEqual(message, result.Message);
        #endregion
    }
}

// Part for GetServiceProvider
services.AddDbContext<ItemDbContext>(
    options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Ignore(CoreEventId.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning));
        options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseInMemoryDatabase("Test");
    });
```

For the duplicate primary key I have an `ArgumentException`.

The both test case doesn't throw exception, the nbRowsImpacted variable is equals to 1. Why ?

Sincerely,
Arai680

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you assume that `_context.SaveChanges` will throw exceptions `InvalidOperationException` or `ArgumentException`. I looked into [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.savechanges?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContext_SaveChanges) and I see that in such case you can expect `DbUpdateException` and `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`. In test you only add one element, so there can't be unique key violation. Maybe in seed method is something interesting, but you didn't paste it.

Comment: I have an InvalidOperationException with an attached entity and an ArgumentException with debugging (for the duplicate primary key). Yes I expected an exception. In some sources on the web, I see an UpdateException in innerException or your exceptions. So I'm not sure what exactly to catch. I'm not capturing them at the moment because I don't have them. As I said, I have an "Ok" insert (with the nbRowsImpacté = 1)